# A hint with a description reminding me of the past

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

A hint with a description reminding me of the past

How to call that hint?  Something about physical ,about time

For example: Look at the bag( a hint) on the tv screen, it is good and reminds me of the birthday gift, a  Gucci bag, you gave me last year

Comment: Check out [synonyms of "reminder".](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reminder)

Comment: Is "reminiscent" the word you're looking for?